# Why does Python's calculation of $0^0$ include the digits of pi?

Tags: limits, computer-science

When you run the following Python code, which is equivalent to $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x$,

```
x = 0.0000000001; print(x ** x)
```

The output will correctly approach 1. (The output is `0.9999999976974149`).

But when you change:

```
x = -0.0000000001
```

Which would be equivalent to $\lim_{x \to 0^-} x^x$, the following output is produced:

```
(1.000000002302585-3.141592660823578e-10j)
```

This is also correct but why do I see an approximation of $\pi$? Surely this can't be a coincidence. Is it the side product of an algorithm that's being used? Or is there a purely mathematical reason for it?

Edit: I only tested it in python. I don't know if similar outputs arise in other programming languages.

Comment: The limit does not exist from the left in the reals , in fact $x^x$ is not even defined for $x<0$ in the reals.  Also note that "$2.302585$" which also occurs is a very good approximation of $\ln(10)$

Comment: Likely because it's doing complex exponentiation. You get like $ R \times CIS (-\pi 10^{-10})$ (with $R\approx 1$), and the CIS expands as $\approx 1 - \pi10^{-10} i $ as $\sin x \approx x$ for small values.

Comment: @Peter ah. missed that. so the answer has to do something with the exponential form of a complex number.

Comment: Exactly: If $x < 0$ is real and $|x| \ll 1$, we have $x^x = e^{x \ln x} = e^{x (\ln (-1) + \ln |x|)} = e^{x(i \pi + \ln |x|)} \approx 1+x(i \pi + \ln |x|) = 1 + x\ln |x| + x i \pi$. Here we have $\ln |x| = \ln 10^{-10} = -10 \ln 10 \approx -23.026$, so $x\ln |x| \approx 2.3026 \times 10^{-9}$.

Comment: That's a bit hard to read, so I made it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding slightly on my comment: If $x < 0$ is real and $|x| \ll 1$, we have

\begin{align}
x^x & = e^{x \ln x} \\
    & = e^{x [\ln |x| + \ln (-1)]} \\
    & = e^{x(\ln |x| + \pi i)} \\
    & \approx 1+x(\ln |x| + \pi i) \\
    & = 1 + x\ln |x| + x \pi i
\end{align}

Here, we have $\ln |x| = \ln 10^{-10} = -10 \ln 10 \approx -23.026$, so $x\ln |x| \approx 2.3026 \times 10^{-9}$, and

\begin{align}
x^x & \approx 1 + 2.3026 \times 10^{-9} - 10^{-10}\pi i \\
    & \approx 1.0000000023026 - 0.000000000314159 i
\end{align}

which reproduces the output of your code.

---

Note that when we have $x = 10^{-10}$ (the positive side), your result is approximately $1-10^{-9} \ln 10$. You may not have noticed this because in one case that small amount was subtracted from $1$, and in the other case it was added to $1$.

Comment: Not only does it contain the digits of $\pi$, it also contains the digits of $\ln 10$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes, that's true, although that's largely a coincidence since the OP chose not just any (negative) power of $10$, but specifically the $-10$th power of $10$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the software calculates an approximation for $x=-10^{-k}$ and complex exponentiation used

$\ln(x)=-k\ln(10)+i\pi+2in\pi\quad$ with principal value $n=0$ used then:

$x^x=\exp\Big(-10^{-k}(-k\ln(10)+i\pi)\Big)=1+k10^{-k}\ln(10)-\pi10^{-k}+o(10^{-k})$

by order $1$ Taylor expansion $e^u=1+u+o(u)$

The displayed result suggest $k=10$ was used, this result in the approximation with $16$ digits:

$x^x\approx 1.000000002302585 - 3.141592653589793e^{-10} i$

Comment: I think our answers were about 10 seconds apart!

Comment: it is a good answer, I upvote it :-)

Comment: I accepted Brians answer, but have my vote, it explains the situation just as well.